# How to create a Funnel Chart in Excel with C# Interop?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I need to create a 'Funnel Chart' in excel through C# using Interop. Directly using Excel there is an option for "Funnel Chart", but through the back end; the enumeration has no option for: "Funnel Chart".

Here's the link on the Enumeration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcharttype?view=excel-pia

I've also tried recording macros while changing the chart type in Excel, but when I look at the VB code in the macro; I find no code for changing the chart type.

Is this a limitation when using Excel Interop?
Is there another way I can achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the alternative I'm using:

```
// Chart
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects mainChartObjects = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects)pivotWorksheet.ChartObjects();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject mainChartObject = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject)mainChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 500, 500);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart mainChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart)mainChartObject.Chart;

ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(pivotTableStartRange, pivotTableEndRange).Select();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fullPivotRange = excelWriter.ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(pivotTableStartRange, pivotTableEndRange);

mainChart.SetSourceData(fullPivotRange);

// Set Chart Type
mainChart.PlotArea.Select();
mainChart.ChartArea.Select();
mainChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlPyramidColStacked;
mainChart.ChartStyle = 419;

// Plot By
mainChart.PlotBy = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows;

// Remove 3D Rotations
Excel.ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select();
Excel.Selection.Format.ThreeD.FieldOfView = 5;
Excel.Selection.Format.ThreeD.RotationX = 0;
Excel.Selection.Format.ThreeD.RotationY = 90;

// Legend
Excel.ActiveChart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementLegendBottom);
```

Chart Type is: Pyramid Column Stacked (3-D Stacked Column)